# Cannot bind to the property or column Date on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

I am displaying the records on datagridview using binding source, but it gives me this error

```
: 'Cannot bind to the property or column Date on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember'
```

here is the snap of Customer table record

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is my code

```
 public void GetData()
        {
            
            obj.GetCon().Open();

            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from Customers", obj.con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            customerBindingSource.DataSource = ds; //it gives error here
            obj.GetCon().Close();


//this is second way i tried but it is also sending the same error.

            //    using (Models.ModelContext db = new Models.ModelContext())
            //{
            //    customerBindingSource.DataSource = db.Customers.ToList();
            //}

            //registeredcustomer_panel.Enabled = true;
            //editinfopanel.Enabled = false;
        }
    
please help me to fix it

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY6Sx.png
```

Comment: From the documentation… [BindingSource.DataSource Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource?view=net-5.0) ... _”When setting a data source, if the supplied reference contains more than one list or table, you must set the DataMember property to a string that specifies the list to bind to.”_ … since a `DataSet` can have multiple `DataTables`, it appears you need to set this property. Or use `ds.Tables[0]` as a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify which `DataSet` table you assign to `customerBindingSource.DataSource`.

```
SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from Customers", obj.con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);  

customerBindingSource.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
customerBindingSource.DataSource = ds; // dataset
customerBindingSource.DataMember = "TableName"; 
obj.GetCon().Close();
```

OR

```
SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from Customers", obj.con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

customerBindingSource.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
customerBindingSource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Don't need to put DefaultView; it happens anyway when you bind dt

Comment: It's also preferable to set DataSource last

Answer (score 0):

The error implies you have set the `customerBindingSource.DataMember` property to `"Date"`

The table you downloaded was called Customers, not Date

You should set the datamember property to the name of the table, i.e. set it to `"Customers"`

---

DataMember is used when DataSource is set to a collection of something  (eg a DataSet is a collection of datatables) and you need to specify *which* something in the collection is to serve as the source of data

You can also set the DataSource directly to the single datatable

When the DataSource is another binding source the DataMember can cite a DataRelation exported by that binding source's datasource, to achieve automatic cascading of related data